# Different font size and gravity for same TextView?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, gravity

I have a textView where I need to have two different fonts for single text and  I need to have left and right gravity for the same text view.

Java code

```
holder.mMessageRowBinding.txtMyRow.setText(messageModel.getMessage()+"  "+CommonFragment.convertServerDateToUserTimeZone(messageModel.getUTCTimeZone(),
                    messageModel.getUTCTimeDate()));
```

XML Code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/layoutThereRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(!messageThread.fromMe ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE),default=gone}">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtThereHeaderName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                android:textColor="@color/halfBlackColor"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtThereRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/halfBlackColor"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Current result: Hi this is StackOverflow 12:37 PM

Comment: You are using recyclerview for this, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using recyclerview

Comment: You can use different view types for incoming and outgoing chats right?

Comment: Yes, I am using different view holders for that, but my issues is with the row, i.e; I want to show the Time "12:24 PM" always right side depends on the message.

Comment: On solution I can suggest is Spannable, will have to check if spannable can alter gravity though. Defenitely it font size can be dealt with Spannable

Comment: Okay, I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

By using SpannableString you can achieve this

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString(messageModel.getMessage()+" "+ 
CommonFragment.convertServerDateToUserTimeZone(messageModel.getUTCTimeZone(),
messageModel.getUTCTimeDate()));
string.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 10, 24, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```